# Add IF statement to Combo Box Linked Cell Excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a cell linked to my ComboBox that displays the dropdown value of the ComboBox.

In another cell, I have IF statements that swap out the numbers based on certain scenarios, like : `=IF(E38=0,C37,E37)`

I tried putting an IF statement where the ComboBox value appears, but, as you guessed, when I run a macro and the ComboBox has to display a new value, the formula is erased.

The Formula I was using was :  `=IF(E38=0,"ComboBox Value",E37)`
 where ComboBox Value was the name currently in the dropdown. 
This didn't work. I know it won't work in the LinkedCell property either.

Is there a way to incorporate this using VBA or a formula or conditional formatting or something?

Thanks in advance.
[image: Regular Case]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this small demo will point you in the right direction. When value in comboBox changes it will change value in cell of your choosing. ignore the debug.print statements and probably want to use the change event not the click event.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Debug.Print ("CHANGED")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Debug.Print ("CHANGED2")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try =INDEX("Input range","Cell link") to get your "ComboBox Value"?

Comment: No I did not. I also do not understand how that would work. Are you saying I replace the `LinkedCell` with this formula instead? And then target the combobox?

Comment: Can you try to load here picture of simple example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you look at the second picture, I want the text "Your Proposal Below" to appear where it is currently saying "Project 1". That is where I tried using an IF statement. The name "Project 1" comes from the combobox LinkedCell property.

Comment: Try to put =IF(E38=0,index("Input range", "Cell link",E37) in the cell C37, where "Input range" and "Cell link" come from the ComboxBox - >Format Control -> Control tab

Answer (score 1):

1. First link combox to one cell, say C1
2. Say, you have to update Range("C2") based on your given conditions.
3. Sub ComboIf()

   If Range("E38").Value = 0 Then
       Range("C2").Value = Range("C1")
       Else: Range("C2").Value = Range("E37")
   End If

   End Sub
4. Now first select a value from combo box, which will update cell C1, then run the macro, it will update C2- if 0, then whatever current combo value you have selected else with whatever value is in E37.